# mySQL- how to show all contact and their status by using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my company Table

```
CompanyID, CompanyName
```

This is my Contact Table

```
ContactID, ContactName, CompanyID
```

This is my Report Table

```
ReportID, ReportName
```

This is my ReportContact Table, Many to Many Relationship

```
ContactID, ReportID
```

I want to return all ALL my CONTACTID of 1 company, include those who are not assign to any report, I also want to return the reportID that are assign to different contacts

1 contacts can be assign to many reports
1 reports can consist of many contacts

My current SQL CODE only manage to get the 2 contactID in the ReportContactTable

```
SELECT rc.ContactID, rc.ReportID  from contact c INNER JOIN Reportcontact rc on c.ContactID = rc.ContactID Where CompanyID=1
```

how can Return all the contact include those not in the reportcontact table, but get the reportID at the same times?

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` filters out those rows that are not in `ReportContact`. Try to use `LEFT JOIN` if you want **all** contacts from `contact` table.

```
SELECT rc.ContactID, rc.ReportID  
  FROM contact c LEFT JOIN Reportcontact rc 
    ON c.ContactID = rc.ContactID
 WHERE CompanyID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do, but if you want all rows from the contact table then you need to use an OUTER rather than INNER join.

Try changing the word INNER to LEFT.

An INNER join ensures that rows that satisfy the join condition appear in both tables.

An OUTER join says "show me all the rows in one table, plus those that satisfy the join condition from the other table". Which table shows all the rows depends on the use of the keywords LEFT and right

`a left join b on a.id = b.id` will show all rows from table a plus those from b which satisfy the join condition

`a right join b on a.id = b.id` will show all rows from table b plus those from a which satisfy the join condition